# VBA MYSQL query: When the variable is a column name

Tags: mysql, vba

When using SQL Server in VBA I would be able to insert the column name as a variable through the following syntax, however I get an error when connecting to Mysql database.

```
column_name = "kills"
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM player_stats_aggregated order by [" & column_name & "] desc "
rs.Open SQLStr, conn, adOpenStatic
```

What is the proper syntax so I can order by the column "kills" descending?

Comment: What are you using now? You talk about SQL Server and MySQL in the same question? Also MySQL does not support brackets

Comment: Sorry I am using Mysql now. Also, this worked when I just removed the bracket.

Comment: On SQL Server you should be using `QUOTENAME` to generate the brackets, i.e. `ORDER BY QUOTENAME(" & column_name & ") DESC` - not sure MySQL has anything like it, but the quoting character in MySQL would be a backtick `\``. If you're not quoting the column name and the `column_name` value comes from user input (directly or not), you're wide open to SQL injection.